# Passing an Array as Parameter to Model in PHP CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, parameters, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to pass as `Array as parameter` to `Stored Procedure` in my `Code-Igniter` application. When I'm print that array it gives me correct result of selected values. But it gives me an error in my model function.

**Here is my controller:**

```
public function index()
{
        $propertyType=$this->input->post('property_type');
        $area=$this->input->post('area_id');
        $clustersID['cluster']=$this->input->post('cluster_id');
        $stageId=$this->input->post('property_status');
        print_r($clustersID);
        $data['properties'] = $this->p->getPropertyByAreaCluster($propertyType, $area, $clustersID, $stageId);

            // echo "<pre>";
            // print_r($data['properties']);
            // echo "</pre>";
            // exit();
            //$data['props'] = $this->p->PropView($propId);
            $this->load->view('template/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('Property/property_view', $data);
            $this->load->view('template/footer');
    }
```

**Here is my Model:**

```
public function getPropertyByAreaCluster($propertyType, $area, $clustersID, $stageId)
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("call fetch_propertyType_Area_Cluster_Stage($propertyType,$area,$clustersID,$stageId)");
        if ($query) {
            $data = $query->result();
            $query->next_result(); 
            $query->free_result();
            return $data;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

***Error:***

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Array to string conversion
>
> Filename: models/Property_m.php
>
> Line Number: 26
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/livemg/application/models/Property_m.php Line:
>   26 Function: _error_handler
>
> File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/livemg/application/controllers/Property.php
>   Line: 61 Function: getPropertyByAreaCluster
>
> File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/livemg/index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once
>
> A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'
>
> call fetch_propertyType_Area_Cluster_Stage(0,0,Array,0)
>
> Filename: models/Property_m.php
>
> Line Number: 26

Comment: try to print clusterId using var_dump() into function

Comment: Where ? In controller or in model function.

Comment: into model function

Comment: Thanks for your reply, got answer.

Comment: Welcome. Good.. :)

Comment: I just post my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer, just convert that array to string and pass it.

```
    public function index()
    {
        $propertyType=$this->input->post('property_type');
        $area=$this->input->post('area_id');
        $clustersID['cluster']=$this->input->post('cluster_id');
        $clusterString = implode(',', $clustersID['cluster']);

        echo "<pre>";
        // var_dump($clustersID['cluster']);
        echo $clusterString;
        echo "</pre>";
        $stageId=$this->input->post('property_status');
        print_r($clustersID);
        $data['properties'] = $this->p->getPropertyByAreaCluster($propertyType, $area, $clustersID, $stageId);

        //$data['props'] = $this->p->PropView($propId);
        $this->load->view('template/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('Property/property_view', $data);
        $this->load->view('template/footer');
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code:

**Controller**

```
public function fetchdata(){
$condition_array = array('category.id' => '1');
                $data = '*';
                $result_category_list = $this->common->select_data_by_condition('category', $condition_array, $data, $sortby = 'category_name', $orderby = 'ASC', $limit = '', $offset = '', $join_str = array());
}
```

**Model**

```
function select_data_by_condition($tablename, $condition_array = array(), $data = '*', $sortby = '', $orderby = '', $limit = '', $offset = '', $join_str = array()) {

        $this->db->select($data);
        $this->db->from($tablename);

        //if join_str array is not empty then implement the join query
        if (!empty($join_str)) {
            foreach ($join_str as $join) {
                if (!isset($join['join_type'])) {
                    $this->db->join($join['table'], $join['join_table_id'] . '=' . $join['from_table_id']);
                } else {
                    $this->db->join($join['table'], $join['join_table_id'] . '=' . $join['from_table_id'], $join['join_type']);
                }
            }
        }

        //condition array pass to where condition
        $this->db->where($condition_array);


        //Setting Limit for Paging
        if ($limit != '' && $offset == 0) {
            $this->db->limit($limit);
        } else if ($limit != '' && $offset != 0) {
            $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
        }

        //order by query
        if ($sortby != '' && $orderby != '') {
            $this->db->order_by($sortby, $orderby);
        }

        $query = $this->db->get();

        //if limit is empty then returns total count
        if ($limit == '') {
            $query->num_rows();
        }
        //if limit is not empty then return result array
        log_message('debug', 'fetching data result:' . $this->db->last_query());
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```